# Angular Material 2 beta 8 MdDialog.afterAllClosed returning undefined result instead of data

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I've been trying to find a solution to my problem, where `result` should return a string from the dialog component's `close` method, but it returns an `undefined`. Was there a bug with this in `angular material 2 beta 8`?

I've been googling a lot, but can't find any info about it. Maybe somebody had a similar situation and managed to solve it?

**Parent component (excerpt):**

```
public openDeleteDialog(): void {
    this.dialog.open(DeleteCompanyDialogComponent, {
      width: environment.dialogSmallWidth,
      height: environment.dialogSmallHeight,
      data: {company: this.company, deleted: false}
    });

    this.dialog.afterAllClosed
      .subscribe(result => {
        console.log(result);
        console.log('delete closed');
      })
  }
```

**Dialog Component (excerpt):**

```
  public closeDialog(): void {
    this.dialogRef.close('LOH');
  }

  onNoClick(): void {
    this.dialogRef.close('LOH');
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing some directives in the html of the dialog component, specifically **mdDialogActions**, **[md-dialog-close]="data"**:

```
<div class="row text-center row-top-padding" mdDialogActions>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6">
    <button md-raised-button
            (click)="closeDialog()">
      <md-icon>restore_page</md-icon>
      {{'COMPANY.DELETE_DIALOG.BUTTON_CANCEL' | translate}}
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6">
    <button md-raised-button
            [md-dialog-close]="data"
            (click)="deleteCompany()"
            class="button-red">
      <md-icon>delete_forever</md-icon>
      {{'COMPANY.DELETE_DIALOG.BUTTON_CONFIRM' | translate}}
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to actually call `afterAllClosed` in order for it to work:

```ts
this.dialog.afterAllClosed() // <- Change this to add paranthesis
  .subscribe(result => {
    console.log(result);
    console.log('delete closed');
  })
```

Comment: This is not a method, but a property in MdDialog. I think you are mistaking this with `afterClosed()`